# Unable to scrape "https" in python 3.7 using beautifulsoup 4.6.3 (Anaconda)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, https, beautifulsoup

Failing to scrape odds from sportsbet.com.au as it is throwing an exception.

I cannot read the exception because the terminal closes too quickly. However, I believe the error is due to scraping from a https site instead of http site.

For example this https site does not work:

https://www.sportsbet.com.au/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki

https://www.google.com/

Neither do websites redirecting to https:

http://www.sportsbet.com.au/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki

http://www.google.com/

However, this website works:

http://www.espncricinfo.com/

The code is as follows:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'website' #insert website link.
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

input("Press enter to exit ;)")
```

I have tried page = requests.get(url,verify=False) with no success.

Comment: "I cannot read the exception because the terminal closes too quickly." Open the terminal window first and invoke your script from the command line. Nobody can help you without information about your error message.

Comment: Solved: Needed to download OpenSSL binaries.